# STAR-Fusion installation fails because of sys/types.h

Tags: c++, linux, perl

Trying to run STAR-Fusion inside Snakemake pipeline on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with this command line :

```
STAR-Fusion --CPU 24 --genome_lib_dir /tmpdata/Gene_Fusion/GRCh37_v19/GRCh37_gencode_v19_CTAT_lib_Mar012021.plug-n-play/ctat_genome_lib_build_dir/ --left_fq /tmpdata/xxx/TX/V1_Intermediate/Gene_Fusion/fastp/4_1_trimmed.fq.gz --right_fq /tmpdata/xxx/TX/V1_Intermediate/Gene_Fusion/fastp/4_2_trimmed.fq.gz --output_dir /tmpdata/xxx/TX/V1_Intermediate/Gene_Fusion/star_fusion/ --FusionInspector validate
```

I get this issue :

```
**Can't locate DB_File.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DB_File module) (@INC contains: /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/Gene_Fusion/STAR-Fusion/util/../PerlLib /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/site_perl/5.32.0 /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/5.32.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/5.32.0 .) at /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/Gene_Fusion/STAR-Fusion/util/../PerlLib/TiedHash.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/Gene_Fusion/STAR-Fusion/util/../PerlLib/TiedHash.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/Gene_Fusion/STAR-Fusion/util/validate_ctat_genome_lib.pl line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/Gene_Fusion/STAR-Fusion/util/validate_ctat_genome_lib.pl line 8.**
```

I did install successfully (inside Snakemake) all the required Perl () libraries, DB_File included :

```
cpan[1]> install DB_File
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 21 Jun 2021 07:56:10 GMT
DB_File is up to date (1.855).
```

So, I checked my STAR-Fusion installation, and when I try to compile it, I get this error :

```
Writing Makefile for Set::IntervalTree
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
make[2] : on entre dans le répertoire « /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/Gene_Fusion/STAR-Fusion/plugins/Set-IntervalTree-0.01 »
Skip blib/lib/Set/IntervalTree.pm (unchanged)
Running Mkbootstrap for IntervalTree ()
chmod 644 "IntervalTree.bs"
"/home/ldap/NJEANRAY/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- IntervalTree.bs blib/arch/auto/Set/IntervalTree/IntervalTree.bs 644
g++ -c  -Isrc -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/perl_1622804860086/work=/usr/local/src/conda/perl-5.32.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/ldap/NJEANRAY/anaconda3/envs/snakemake=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -O0   -DVERSION=\"0.01\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.01\" -fPIC --sysroot=/bin/..//x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot "-I/home/ldap/NJEANRAY/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/perl5/5.32/core_perl/CORE"  -Isrc IntervalTree.c
In file included from IntervalTree.xs:6:
/home/ldap/NJEANRAY/anaconda3/envs/snakemake/lib/perl5/5.32/core_perl/CORE/perl.h:822:10: fatal error: sys/types.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
  822 | #include <sys/types.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:341 : IntervalTree.o] Erreur 1
make[2] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/Gene_Fusion/STAR-Fusion/plugins/Set-IntervalTree-0.01 »
make[1]: *** [Makefile:3 : all] Erreur 2
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /home/ldap/NJEANRAY/Gene_Fusion/STAR-Fusion/plugins »
make: *** [Makefile:3 : all] Erreur 2
(snakemake) NJEANRAY@OCS-NJE:~/Gene_Fusion
```

But sys/types.h does exist in /usr/include/sys :

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    29 déc.  16  2020 types.h -> ../i386-linux-gnu/sys/types.h

Could you please advice ?

Thanks

Comment: See also [this](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/24709) and [this](https://github.com/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/issues/24688) issue.

Comment: Note the `-isystem` flag prohibits gcc from looking under /usr/include.